# PowerShell object browser

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

I vaguely remember a tool I used in the dark ages of PS 2.0. The best I can describe it is, you pipe an object to it, and it gives you a GUI that lets you "browse" or "explore" the object. It's sort of like Out-Gridview, but you can expand nested objects.

This is the closest I could find below. However, from the description it sounds like this Object Browser looks at Everything in the PowerShell Environment.
https://web.archive.org/web/20210126090047/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Object-Browser-847d62c1 (described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28651.how-to-create-and-use-an-object-browser-in-powershell.aspx))

Does that sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Yes, sound familiar. What is the problem/issue/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article describing `Show-Object`, a command from the PowerShellCookbook module.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/spelunking-with-show-object/

I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly that. Thank you very much!

Comment: It appears that the PowerShellCookbook module hasn't been updated since 2016 and doesn't work on PowerShell Core 7.x on macOS.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellCookbook